# VPN, routing and bridging two networks together

Tags: windows, vpn, routing

I have a site which I can VPN into via a Cisco RV082 10/100 8 Port VPN router.  The IP address subnet on the LAN is 192.168.3.0.

One Windows machine on this network contains two network cards which is used to bridge or connect to a second network.  This second network contains addresses in a 192.168.149.0 range. Hence the machine with two network cards has two IP addresses: 192.168.3.10 and 192.168.149.71.

When I connect to the site via the VPN, I can reach all the devices on the 192.168.3.0 network from the remote client. However, I was wondering if there's a way to connect to the devices on the 192.168.149 network via the machine which has the two network cards.

Can this be done by bridging the two LAN connections together?